# content inside popup not display in IE 9

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-9, bpopup

content inside div is not displaying in Ie9.Its display in all other browsers?

```
<div id="element_to_pop_up2"   style="z-index:9999999">

    <a href="#" class="b-close">x</a>

     **There will be Delay with shipping this week.**
    </div>
```

---

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#element_to_pop_up2').bPopup({
              speed: 650,
              transition: 'slideIn'
       });
    });
```

Comment: To clarify; the pop up appears but has no content? Or there is no pop up?

Comment: popup comes..But with no content in IE9.thats the problem.

Comment: Use a plugin where the creator actually has a clue what they're doing? Seriously the example code on the popups page is all wrong.... If the pop up is there but no content try wrapping the text in p tags.

Comment: Yes, you should test the plugin with IE9 on their pages to make sure it is not a bug with the 3rd party.  Otherwise, are you getting any JS errors when you load the page or click the popup trigger?

Comment: Hi rick  i am using this plugin:  jquery.bpopup.min.js.Its working fine in all browser excpet IE9.

Answer (score 0):

See my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rYLu8/1/ where I've litterally copied your code, and copied the code from the JS (as couldn't be served from GitHub directly)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#element_to_pop_up2').bPopup({
          speed: 650,
          transition: 'slideIn'
   });
});
```

It seems to "work" for me on FF, Chrome and IE9 - however I wouldn't describe it as "working properly" in any situation, as it seems to only center the content once you resize the window, which doesn't make sense.

In conclusion, I'm guessing there's something wrong with your code, but I'd seriously recommend looking at something a bit better (and without some juvenile tagline) such as http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals or http://jqueryui.com/dialog/, they'll be easier to use, more reliable across browsers, and they have a huge community of people you can ask if you ever get stuck.